# Collections.sort with 2 array

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have 2 `ArrayList`s. The first one keep the indexes of how the elements should be ordered in the second `ArrayList`. How can I group elements from `ArrayList` 2 by using their proper index from `ArrayList` 1?

My code:

```
public void createRolette(Population population) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> rouletteId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> rouletteFit = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i=0; i<populationSize; i++) {
        population.getIndividual(i);
        Simulator.allocateTask(i);
        rouletteId.add(i);
        rouletteFit.add(calcFitness(i));
    }
    //   Collections.sort(rouletteFit);
```

My output:

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49]
>   [90, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 90, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 88, 86, 88, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86, 86]

I'm trying to use this given solution but there are some mistakes in the code that I can't fix.

```
public abstract class Roulette implements Comparable<Roulette>{

 super();   //here says "Syntax error on token "super", Identifier expected"
int rouletteId;
int rouletteFit;

public Roulette(int rouletteId, int rouletteFit){
    this.rouletteId = rouletteId;
    this.rouletteFit = rouletteFit;
}

public int getId(){
    return rouletteId;
}

public int getFit(){
    return rouletteFit;
}

public static Comparator<Roulette> FitComparator = new Comparator<Roulette>() {

public int compare(Roulette r1, Roulette r2) {

  int fit1 = r1.getFit();
  int fit2 = r2.getFit();

  //ascending order
  return fit1.compareTo(fit2);

  //descending order
  //return fit2.compareTo(fit1);
}

};



public void createRoulette(Population population) throws Exception {
ArrayList<Roulette> rouletteList = new ArrayList<Roulette>();

for (int i=0; i<population.size(); i++){
   population.getIndividual(i);
   Simulator.allocateTask(i);
   Roulette r = new Roulette(i, Simulator.calcFitness(i)); // here in "new Roulette says // - Multiple markers at this line
//- Cannot instantiate the type Roulette
//- Line breakpoint:Roulette [line: 48]

 createRoulette(Population)
   rouletteList.add(r);
}

   Collections.sort(rouletteList, Roulette.FitComparator);
}
}
```

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for some kind of [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)? Because I have no idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is a classic exercise when learning algorithms.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, can you translate to us in English what the OP is asking or even better edit and improve the question so the requirements are clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also implement your own sorting algorithm and swap values from the two arrays. Following uses Bubble Sort, a simple sorting algorithm.

```
public static void createRolette(Population population) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Integer> rouletteId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> rouletteFit = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int swap;

    for (int i=0; i<populationSize; i++){
        population.getIndividual(i);
        Simulator.allocateTask(i);
        rouletteId.add(i); 
        rouletteFit.add(calcFitness(i)); 
    }

    //Bubble Sort
    for (int i = 0; i < ( rouletteFit.size() - 1 ); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < rouletteFit.size() - i - 1; j++) {
            if (rouletteFit.get(j) > rouletteFit.get(j+1))
            {
                swap       = rouletteFit.get(j);
                rouletteFit.set(j, rouletteFit.get(j+1));
                rouletteFit.set(j+1, swap);

                swap       = rouletteId.get(j);
                rouletteId.set(j, rouletteId.get(j+1));
                rouletteId.set(j+1, swap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bubblesort is not an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Bubblesort is order of O(n^2) at the worst case but it is very efficient if your arrays are sorted or nearly sorted. So, I prefer to say that all algorithms are efficient in case you make the good choices. Anyway this was just an example.

Comment: lol, all sorting algorithms are very efficient if they *sorted or nearly sorted* ;).

Answer (score 0):

You can create an arraylist of objects, with an ID and Fit, or you can keep the logic you have with two [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) rather than two arraylists.

```
public class Roulette implements Comparable<Roulette>{
    super();
    int rouletteId;
    int rouletteFit;

    public Roulette(int rouletteId, int rouletteFit){
        this.rouletteId = rouletteId;
        this.rouletteFit = rouletteFit;
    }

    public int getId(){
        return rouletteId;
    }

    public int getFit(){
        return rouletteFit;
    }

    public static Comparator<Roulette> FitComparator 
                      = new Comparator<Roulette>() {

    public int compare(Roulette r1, Roulette r2) {

      int fit1 = r1.getFit();
      int fit2 = r2.getFit()

      //ascending order
      return (fit1 - fit2);

      //descending order
      //return (fit2 -fit1);
    }

    };

}

public void createRoulette(Population population) throws Exception {
    ArrayList<Roulette> rouletteList = new ArrayList<Roulette>();

    for (int i=0; i<populationSize; i++){
       population.getIndividual(i);
       Simulator.allocateTask(i);
       Roulette r = new Roulette(i, calcFitness(i));
       rouletteList.add(r)
    }

   Collections.sort(rouletteList, Roulette.FitComparator);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to use your code Petrov but is giving many errors.

Answer (score 0):

With your current implementation of the ArrayLists, you cannot simply call `Collections.sort()` to group your array list of Fit's and the mappings to your id's the same.  To implement this you basically have 3 options:

1. Create your own sorting Algorithm:  You can easily implement a simple sorting algorithm that will group the values of `rouletteFit` and also reorganize the corresponding indexes in `rouletteId`.
2. Implement a custom `Class` that implements `Comparable<ClassName>`.  This will allow you to build a class that contains both the id, and the Fit in one object, and allows you to write a custom `compareTo()` method, so you can simply use `Collections.Sort()`.
3. Create a Map: You can use the `HashMap` class to store the fit values as keys, and have an `ArrayList` of indexes that use that fit.  The definition would look like `HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> map;`